# finding and updating an object in a mongo db document in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

So im trying to find and update a documnet's nested object in a mongo db collection. Im using the exact procedure i used on updating the other fields in that document but its failing to find and update on this specific execution. Weird thing is when i do a findOne its returning the document successfully but as soon as i findOneAndUpdate its not executing.

this is the implementation thats giving me problems
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIdv.png)

and this is an example of the implementations that are working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVbYR.png)

i was expecting that same document thats being returned to also be updated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/errors/backtraces/etc. - just include the text in a codeblock.